# Re-enter the value that is in the mysql query into the variable

Tags: mysql, c++builder

I have a lot of problems in my program, before that I will explain the workflow of my program, first the program is run then the user enters the value where the value entered by the user is stored into the variable and then the variable value  also stored in the mysql table, so that when the program stops running and starts again, the value in the variable is still in accordance with the last value entered by the user, not the default value, now I have successfully entered the value entered by the user into the mysql table but I cannot enter the values ​​in the mysql table into variable, please help my problem,

I want to enter the value ​​in the table "NO" into the "n" variable

the values ​​in the "CUSTOMER" table into the "ns [n] .name" variable

the values ​​in the table "BALANCE "into the variable" ns [n] .saldo [0]"

the value in the table" DEBIT_KREDIT "into the variable" ns [n] .dk [0] "

the value is yes ng is in the table "ACCOUNT" into variable "rekenig [n]"

this is the code, I am using a c ++ builder application, please help me

```
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "Unit3.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;

struct nasabah{
        AnsiString nama;
        int pin;
        int saldo[100];
        int dk[100];
}ns[100];

int rekening[100]={111342,111343,111344,111345,111346,111347,111348,111349,111350
,111411,111412,111413};
int n=0, m=0, g, store, saldoplus, tarik, kirim, norek, no;
AnsiString inama;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::bdaftarkanClick(TObject *Sender)
{
Edit8->Text=n;
ns[n].nama=Edit1->Text;
ns[n].saldo[0]=StrToInt(Edit2->Text);
ns[n].pin=StrToInt(Edit3->Text);
ns[n].dk[0]=ns[n].saldo[0];
if (ns[n].saldo[0]<100000){
         Application->MessageBoxA("Maaf... Saldo tidak boleh kurang dari 100000","Customer Service",MB_OK);
}else{
if (Application->MessageBoxA("Apakah Data Tersebut Sudah Benar?", "Konfirmasi", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION)==IDYES){
 Form3->ListBox3->Clear();
 Form3->ListBox2->Clear();
 Form3->ListBox1->Clear();
 Form3->Label4->Caption=ns[n].nama;
 Form3->Label5->Caption=rekening[n];
 Form3->ListBox1->Items->Add(ns[n].dk[0]);
 Form3->ListBox2->Items->Add(ns[n].saldo[0]);
 Form3->Show();
 Form3->ListBox3->Items->Add(Date());
 Label2->Hide();
 Label3->Hide();
 Label4->Hide();
 Label13->Hide();
 Edit1->Hide();
 Edit2->Hide();
 Edit3->Hide();
 bdaftarkan->Hide();

bpendaftaran->Show();
bcetakbuku->Show();

ADOQuery1->Close();
ADOQuery1->SQL->Clear();
ADOQuery1->ConnectionString=("Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=sfti");
ADOQuery1->SQL->Add("INSERT INTO data_nasabah (NO, NASABAH, TANGGAL, SALDO, DEBIT_KREDIT, REKENING) values ('" +n+ "','" +ns[n].nama+ "','" +Date()+ "','" +ns[n].saldo[0]+ "','" +ns[n].dk[0]+ "','" +rekening[n]+ "')");
ADOQuery1->ExecSQL();
n+=1;
}
else {
 ShowMessage("Silahkan perbaiki data anda...");
}}

void __fastcall TForm2::BkonfirmasiClick(TObject *Sender)
{
Form3->ListBox3->Clear();
Form3->ListBox2->Clear();
Form3->ListBox1->Clear();
inama=Edit4->Text;
int ketemu=0;
g=0;
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
       if(inama==ns[i].nama){
                ketemu++;
                Form3->Label4->Caption=ns[i].nama;
                Form3->Label5->Caption=rekening[i];
                do{
                        Form3->ListBox2->Items->Add(ns[i].saldo[g]);
                        Form3->ListBox1->Items->Add(ns[i].dk[g]);
                        Form3->ListBox3->Items->Add(Date());
                        g = g + 1;
                        }while (ns[i].saldo[g]&&ns[i].dk!=0);
       Form3->Show();
       Bkonfirmasi->Hide();
       Edit4->Hide();
       Label5->Hide();
       Label14->Hide();}
}
       if (ketemu==0){
                Application->MessageBoxA("Nama anda tidak terdaftar","Customer Service",MB_OK);
       }
bpendaftaran->Show();
bcetakbuku->Show();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------



void __fastcall TForm2::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Form3->ListBox3->Clear();
Form3->ListBox2->Clear();
Form3->ListBox1->Clear();
int ketemu=0;
g=0;
inama=Edit5->Text;
store=StrToInt(Edit6->Text);

for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
       if(inama==ns[i].nama){
                ketemu++;
                m++;
                Form3->Label4->Caption=ns[i].nama;
                Form3->Label5->Caption=rekening[i];
                for(int s=0; s<=m;s++){
                if(ns[i].saldo[s]==0){
                saldoplus=ns[i].saldo[s-1];
                ns[i].saldo[s]=saldoplus+store;
                ns[i].dk[s]=store;
                break;
               } }
           do{
                Form3->ListBox2->Items->Add(ns[i].saldo[g]);
                Form3->ListBox1->Items->Add(ns[i].dk[g]);
                Form3->ListBox3->Items->Add(Date());
                g = g+1;
                }while (ns[i].saldo[g]&&ns[i].dk[g]!=0);
                Form3->Show();
       }
}
       if(ketemu==0){
                Application->MessageBoxA("Nama anda tidak terdaftar","Customer Service",MB_OK);
       }
Edit5->Clear();
Edit6->Clear();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::Button5Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Form3->ListBox3->Clear();
Form3->ListBox2->Clear();
Form3->ListBox1->Clear();

int ketemu=0;
g=0;
inama=Edit5->Text;
tarik=StrToInt(Edit6->Text);

for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
       if(inama==ns[i].nama){
                ketemu++;
                m++;
                Form3->Label4->Caption=ns[i].nama;
                Form3->Label5->Caption=rekening[i];
                for(int s=0; s<=m;s++){
                if(ns[i].saldo[s]==0){
                saldoplus=ns[i].saldo[s-1];
                if (saldoplus>=tarik){
                        ns[i].saldo[s]=saldoplus-tarik;
                        ns[i].dk[s]=tarik*-1;


                do{
                        Form3->ListBox2->Items->Add(ns[i].saldo[g]);
                        Form3->ListBox1->Items->Add(ns[i].dk[g]);
                        Form3->ListBox3->Items->Add(Date());
                        g = g+1;
                }while (ns[i].saldo[g]&&ns[i].dk[g]!=0);
                Form3->Show();
                break;
       }else{
                Application->MessageBoxA("Saldo anda tidak mencukupi","TELLER",MB_OK);
                break;
       }
       } }}
}
       if(ketemu==0){
                Application->MessageBoxA("Nama anda tidak terdaftar","TELLER",MB_OK);
       }
Edit5->Clear();
Edit6->Clear();

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::Button6Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Form3->ListBox3->Clear();
Form3->ListBox2->Clear();
Form3->ListBox1->Clear();
g=0;
int ketemu=0;
int mentume=0;
inama=Edit5->Text;
kirim=StrToInt(Edit6->Text);
norek=StrToInt(Edit7->Text);

for (int h=0; h<=n; h++){
        mentume+=1;
        if(norek==rekening[h]){
                for(int o=0; o<=m;o++){
                if(ns[h].saldo[o]==0){
                        saldoplus=ns[h].saldo[o-1];
                        ns[h].saldo[o]=saldoplus+kirim;
                        ns[h].dk[o]=kirim;
                        break;
                }}
        }
}
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
       if(inama==ns[i].nama){
                ketemu+=1;
                m++;
                Form3->Label4->Caption=ns[i].nama;
                Form3->Label5->Caption=rekening[i];
                for(int s=0; s<=m;s++){
                if(ns[i].saldo[s]==0){
                        saldoplus=ns[i].saldo[s-1];
                        ns[i].saldo[s]=saldoplus-kirim;
                        ns[i].dk[s]=kirim*-1;
                        break;
                }}
                do{
                Form3->ListBox2->Items->Add(ns[i].saldo[g]);
                Form3->ListBox1->Items->Add(ns[i].dk[g]);
                Form3->ListBox3->Items->Add(Date());
                g = g+1;
                }while (ns[i].saldo[g]&&ns[i].dk[g]!=0);
                Form3->Show();
       }
}

if(ketemu==0||mentume==0){
        Application->MessageBoxA("Nama atau No Rekening tidak ditemukan","TELLER",MB_OK);
}

Edit5->Clear();
Edit6->Clear();
Edit7->Clear();

}
```

Comment: How do you plan to assign value from MySQL table into variable when you don't query the table? I mean, I can see `INSERT` query but there's no `SELECT` query there..

Comment: I have made it but an error, so I ask for help to make it here or an example to make it fit with my program

Comment: You should focus on what you've tried and post the error message you've received in your attempt. Currently, you're just posting a very long code and I'm afraid most people will ignore your question and flagged it as unclear. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66881394/edit) with lesser code and (any) error message(s) you've found. Thanks

Comment: My use a mySQL table to save a few variables ? Why not use an INI file (TIniFile object)?